# AD Sites & Services - KCC Auto Generated Connections

Tags: active-directory

As I understanding it, the KCC will auto generate connections for replication.  I was told by a co-worker that this only occurs for the first 5 domain controllers, which is why he has manually created additional connections.  Is this correct? If so, can someone point me to the technet article related to this? Are AD is running at 2008 R2 domain and forest functional levels.  Any input would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> As I understanding it, the KCC will auto generate connections for replication.

Overall, yes this is correct

> I was told by a co-worker that this only occurs for the first 5 domain controllers, which is why he has manually created additional connections.

This is **incorrect**.

The Knowledge Consistency Checker runs on all domain controllers to ensure a [consistent replication topology](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756899(v=ws.10).aspx), and operates on two levels:

1. *Intra*-site topology generation:

   - The KCC on each and every Domain Controller reviews the existing connection objects between the Domain Controllers in its own Site, and creates new connections objects for inbound replication if it determines that the current intra-site topology is in a state where the local DC might miss any updates from the other Domain Controllers in the Site.
2. *Inter*-site topology generation:

   - In each Site, a single Domain Controller is elected to have the role of [**Inter-Site Topology Generator** (ISTG)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224815) - that is, a single Domain Controller responsible for reviewing and managing connection objects to that site. Unlike the topology generation algorithm that runs the Intra-site topology generation on each DC, the ISTG operation assigns connection objects to the Domain Controller elected or designated **Bridgehead Server** for the Site, instead of to itself. The Bridgehead Server and the ISTG for a given Site may or may not be the same Domain Controller.

These operations occur without regards to the number of Domains, Sites or Domain Controllers, and repeats every 15 minutes.

I'm currently working with a large corporate client who has ~110 Domain Controllers deployed in 30+ Sites, servicing 8 Domains. We've simply defined a meticulously costed Site Link topology that matches the underlying network infrastructure, and the KCC takes care of the rest.

**Note:** The links I've provided were written for Windows 2000 Advanced and Windows Server 2003, but the truth is that the implementation details of this part of active directory haven't changed significantly since the first release of Active Directory, and will apply to Windows 2008 R2 and above as well

Comment: +1. Just to add, Microsoft says: "Adding connections is not recommended because extra connections gradually reduce the ability of the KCC to automatically choose the best configurations. In addition, you create a situation where you must continually evaluate whether the manual connections are doing the best possible job of replicating changes." http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961787.aspx